# Something wrong with a Haskell List

Tags: list, haskell, head

I do not know what happened with this.
I have a list 
`L = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]`

and i need a function that gives me this:
`L = [[1, 4, 7],[2, 5, 8],[3, 6, 9]]`

until now i have this:

```
rotar2 [ ] = [ ]
rotar2 l = [map head l] ++ rotar2(map tail l)
```

and it works but not at all..
it sends me this error:

`[[1,4,7],[2,5,8],[3,6,9],[ 
  Program error: pattern match failure: head []`

what should i do?

Comment: The function you're trying to define is readily available - it's called [`transpose`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Data-List.html#v:transpose).

Comment: What happens when you do `rotar2 [[]]`?

Comment: @n.m. it sends me the same error

Comment: I know what it sends you, can you see why?

Comment: You `map head` on `l`, but there is no reason to assume that `l` contains non-empty lists simply because `l` itself is non-empty. If you continue to `map tail` on a lists of lists, eventually, one of the elements will be an empty list.

Comment: @user2407038 i already know that

Comment: @IvanG4Life Great, so add a pattern which handles that case.

Comment: @FrerichRaabe ok, but i need to import some library? sends me: `ERROR: - Undefined variable "transpose"`

Comment: @IvanG4Life the `transpose` function is in the `Data.List` module, so you'd have to add an `import Data.List` at the top of your program to get it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are repeatedly taking the heads and tails of every list in your function's input. Eventually, one of these lists will only have the empty list left as a tail and attempting to take the head of that empty list will then fail.

```
  rotar2 [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
    = [[1,4,7]] ++ rotar2 [[2,3], [5,6], [8,9]]
    = [[1,4,7]] ++ [[2,5,8]] ++ rotar2 [[3], [6], [9]]
    = [[1,4,7]] ++ [[2,5,8]] ++ [[3,6,9]] ++ rotar2 [[],[],[]]
    = [[1,4,7]] ++ [[2,5,8]] ++ [[3,6,9]] ++ [head [],head[],head []] ++ ...
    = [[1,4,7],[2,5,8],[3,6,9],[⊥,⊥,⊥],...]
```

#### Transpose

The function `rotar2` that you are trying to define is usually called `transpose` and can be implemented rather straightforwardly as

```
transpose :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
transpose []         = repeat []
transpose (xs : xss) = zipWith (:) xs (transpose xss)
```

The idea is that a nonempty list of lists, say `[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]`, can be transposed inductively by first transposing its tail `[[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]`, yielding `[[4,7],[5,8],[6,9]]`, and then prepending the elements of the head list `[1,2,3]` to the elements of the transposed tail:

```
[ 1 : [4,7] , 2 : [5,8] , 3 : [6,9] ]
```

Hence:

```
> transpose [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
[[1,4,7],[2,5,8],[3,6,9]]
```

In the standard libraries, this function is exported by the module [`Data.List`](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch20.html#x28-23000020.2).

Answer (score 0):

You can redefine the `transpose` function in one line:

```
transpose = getZipList . traverse ZipList
```

All the definitions and instances are in the `Control.Applicative` and `Data.Traversable` modules. It's the same definition as in the Stefan Holdermans answer modulo typeclasses and wrapping-unwrapping stuff.